# Compare log4j and Logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j

How does The JDK's [Logger](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) compare to Apache [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/)?

Which one is better for new projects that target Java 6?  How do they compare in terms of flexibility and configurability?

Comment: Pretty much anything is better than `java.util.logging`, even if it means introducing a 3rd-party dependency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To my mind the only thing the JDK Logger has going for it is that it is part of the JDK, so it doesn't add an external dependency. If the choice is only between those two, I'd go with Log4j. It still has better support in terms of appenders, the number of people who know it (in my anecdotal observations), and a better API (that is subjective as well).

Starting a project today, the most tempting thing to do is go with slf4j and deffer the decision - you can always plug in a different framework underneath slf4j by just changing the classpath.

That being said there are other options (such as Log5j) that take advantage of the latest Java language features. I'd recommend taking a long look [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) (from one of the main programmers of Log4j, as is slf4j).

Comment: After reviewing Logback, I think I'll use it for new projects without any library dependancies on log4j, and log4j otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I've never used the direct JDK logger, but for a new project I'd highly reccomend [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), 
designed as a successor for log4j. Some of the very nice things you can do with it:

- printf style parameter building, no more messy concatenating strings protected by if logger.isDebugEnabled() guards.

go from

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled())
 { 
    log.warn (i + "many ints,"+ l+"many longs");
}
```

to

```
log.debug("{} many ints, {} many longs", i, l);
```

- very flexible config, including configurations that will print traces. The config is xml, but their site includes a utility that will generate an xml config from your log4j config to get you started.

Downside - lots of packages require log4j anyway, since it's so common, so your project may need to include 2 logging packages.

Comment: The existent log4j dependency makes me tempted to stick to it for such projects!

Answer (score 3):

For a new project I would strongly recommend the slf4j project which provides  generic frontend to several logger frameworks.

The {}-syntax described by Steve B is present in slf4j too (same author) so you get all the benefits regardless of backend, and STILL get the backend independency.  Also a log4j bridge is available so existing code transparently can use slf4j.  It is really nice.

For actual backend, logback is nice but you may already have invested in log4j  -  this is easily leveragable.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [JDK logging API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html). I have used it for many years, without any problem whatsoever. It's part of the JDK, so no extra jar is required. The distinctions between log4j and JDK logging are small, and, in my opinion, don't justify the use of log4j.

Answer (score 1):

***Standard API vs log4j***

A common question asked by Java developers is:

> Why we should use log4j logging framework when Java provides an API
>   for logging. The java API can be accessed by (java.util.logging)?

Log4j has following advantages over standard logging API:

- log4j provides robust logging
- log4j has more features available than standard logging API
- configuring and using log4j is easier
- log4j also has a much more robust formatting system
- many add-on programs and handlers are available for log4j

Comment: This common question is exactly what I am currently pondering (and why I am here), but this answer confuses me more. In this answer, what exactly is meant by 'robust', why is log4j more robust? When it comes to 'more features', are there any highlights? Again with the robustness, what is a robust formatting system? I will admit I am 'new' to logging in java, but these implementations seem awfully over the top for most small-medium applications.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this question several times; with jdk7 and jdk8; java logging super fast and slick, but only thing we need to put programmer hat while configuring.

To log to multiple file destiantions, we neeed to create signare classes extending FielHandler and use them in properties file to configure, this kind intricacies appears time consuming but once you get hang efficiency and reliability are awesome.