# Which API Should I use to log in java

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

I am building a mid-sized standalone console based java application and I must log various events that can take place. I am not sure about which API to use. I have looked upon [Logback Project](http://logback.qos.ch/) and [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/). I am concerned if these are the right one, since both of the seem to have extensive uses in the web application projects. Please help me decide if I am better using the default java.util.logging API or should I use another frameworks; if so which one.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375911/compare-log4j-and-logger

Comment: Did you check if they are used in desktop projects? In any case, the question is not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354837/whats-up-with-logging-in-java

Comment: This blog provides an interesting overview: http://antoniogoncalves.org/2012/09/06/i-need-you-for-logging-api-spec-lead/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend `slf4j`.(it's written by the same guy who did log4j) You can read more from [here](http://www.slf4j.org/)

Comment: @codeMan - well slf4j is a facade ... not a framework.